# How to evaluate if I have built a good model?

Tags: deep-learning

I am  new with deep learning. My  first exercise was with a simple convolution neural network, I use keras, This is a summary about my first model:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 35, 8)             136
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 17, 8)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 17, 8)             0
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 10, 8)             520
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1 (None, 5, 8)              0
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_3 (MaxPooling1 (None, 2, 8)              0
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling1d_1 ( (None, 8)                 0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 8)                 0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               2304
=================================================================
Total params: 2,960
Trainable params: 2,960
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

My first exercise was with a convolution neural network including LSTM model. This is my summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 35, 8)             136
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 17, 8)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 17, 8)             0
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 10, 8)             520
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1 (None, 5, 8)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 5, 8)              0
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 5, 32)             5248
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 5, 32)             8320
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 5, 32)             8320
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, 5, 32)             8320
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_5 (LSTM)                (None, 32)                8320
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               8448
=================================================================
```

HoWever,I am not able to evaluate my models, how can I evaluate them? Did I have enough of layer i each model? Must I add other layers? or must I delete some layers?

I would be very grateful if you could help.

Comment: If you found any of the provided answers helpful / solving your problem, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2):

In gerneral it is a smart move to partition your date into 3 subsets:

**Training**: Part of the data you train your network on.

**Validation**: Part of the data used for fine tuning hyperparameters and early stopping if you use it.

**Test**: Part of the data you hold out during the whole training and fine tuning process. This data should not be analyzed until your algorithm is finalized. Predicting and measuring the accuracy on this data will give you the best hint regarding how your algorithm performs on unseen data.

Generally I would start with more basic machine learning algorithms like linear and logistic regression to learn those basics and then move to more complicated ones like CNNs and LSTMs. Try searching for 'data partitioning for machine learning' and you'll get many explanations regarding this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Bit short, but *can't you do it as always*?:

1. split you data into training and testing,
2. train the NN on the training data
3. let the NN predict the testing data, compare predicted labels/values to actual labels/values